# Do we ever see a 0-G environment on a Holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, holodeck, artificial-gravity

I was reading the *TNG* Bible and found the following excerpt about Holodecks:

> In the holodecks, almost any kind of recreation, training or exercise can be simulated, especially since these same decks can also make potent use of the **starship's gravity control system.**  This also permits, for example, the challenge of skiing any real or imaginable slope or **engaging in a variety of mid-air low gravity games and contests.**

Now, the thought struck me; I don't *ever* recall seeing a 0-G (or even reduce gravity) environment simulated on the Holodeck in *TNG*.  **Are there any instances in *TNG* of a simulate environment with changed gravity conditions?**

If there are no instances from *TNG*, instances from *DS9* or *VOY* will also be accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Not directly in TNG

In *[Conundrum](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Conundrum_%28episode%29)*, we see:

> Dr. Beverly Crusher tending to Kristin, a crewmember injured cliff-diving on the holodeck

that holodeck program was [Holodeck Program 47-C](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holodeck_Program_47-C).  So, although *we* don't observe it in *TNG*, we assume that in *TNG* the holodek could manipulate gravity with this program, otherwise Kristin would've fallen straight to the ground!  She must have been suspended for a period of time before the jump ended.

In *VOY* though we *do* see gravity in operation in *[Extreme Risk](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Extreme_Risk_%28episode%29)*:

> On board an orbital shuttle, B'Elanna Torres is preparing for **orbital
>   skydiving in the holodeck**...[later she] **jump[s] out of the shuttle**...

So, in order for Torres to accomplish that jump without jumping right onto the floor of the holodeck, the gravity in the holodeck must have been altered.

So, **yes, we *do* see the holodeck manipulate gravity, but not in *TNG***

Comment: Also, although not observable directly, one would assume that anytime the holodeck recreates an alien world, the gravity is set to match the surface parameters of that world.   (Since everyone always ooh and ahhs over how good the reproduction is.)   So we probably have seen it.  But why virtually all the planets we know about are portrayed to have exactly a 1.0G surface is another question.

Comment: (For example, Vulcan is known to have considerably higher temperature and surface gravity, but no one every says, "Hey this is a great Vulcan, but I feel too light" so the gravity must be manipulated.)

Answer (score 2):

In "Extreme risk" when Torres ended the simulation while skydiving, the holodeck erased the planet and space visuals and kept her afloat for a few seconds while rotating her to her feet to prevent her fromlanding on her face. That was actual zero-G rather than freefall.

Comment: hello Some dude and welcome to scifi&fantasySE. Can you back your answer with some proof (video, interview..), cheers!