# Was there ever a scene with people in zero gravity in TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was perusing the site, and it suddenly occourred to me that I don't remember any scenes from TNG with people floating around in microgravity, spacewalks or otherwise.

Are there any? Or was convincing zero-g effects too difficult for the time?

Comment: Related, not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100500/22917

Comment: Does it have to be the television series, or do *TNG*-era films count?

Comment: There's Spock's space walk in *The Motion Picture*, but that's not TNG!

Comment: @N_Soong : They float in space by the deflector dish in *First Contact*...

Comment: @Praxis Films included.

Comment: Also there's a ***lot*** of 0g on a Klingon ship in, I believe, *The Undiscovered Country*.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Definitely!  (Just not a *TNG* film.)

Comment: @Praxis:  for everyone's general interest, it's notable because of all the free-floating CG Klingon blood effects.

Comment: I don't think their special-effects budget covers anything that can't be done in post-production

Comment: If DS9 counts, http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Melora_(episode)

Comment: @Omegacron:   Good point -- lots of shots, definitely controlled flight.

Comment: Are you interested in specifically, TNG's crew (Picard, Riker, et all plus other characters), or any example from the TNG era (of which would include DS9 and Voyager)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, **this guy**.  A Romulan is shown free-floating in space after La Forge pushes him through the hull in the *TNG* episode "The Next Phase".

[image]

Comment: Oh man, so many good answers. I don't know which one to choose!

Comment: @DC177E : The Trek fans here are quite active, so you can often expect a selection of good answers. Given that ThePopMachine found what is likely the first example in *TNG*, you made the best choice!  :-)

Comment: Added screencap

Comment: @Praxis:  edited text; 《wink》

Comment: @ThePopMachine : *This guy*.  Love it.

Comment: @Praxis: Night Terrors was in season four, The Next Phase is season five. Good example though and not as embarrassing as Night Terrors.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how many Star Trek questions can be answered with "this guy"

Comment: @muistooshort:   Well, "Night Terrors" is floating in a dream.   It's not incontrovertible that that's zero-g.   People float in dreams all the time.   People do it in non-scifi shows too, so I'm not convinced it counts.

Answer (score 24):

In the *TNG*-era film ***First Contact***, Picard floats in space from one side of deflector dish to the other, when he turns off the magnetism on his boots.

[image]

(In a later film, ***Nemesis***, the Enterprise bridge itself is torn open during battle and an officer is sucked out into space.  It would be difficult to call this floating or walking, however, given the forces involved.)

Comment: Wow, nice. I'll accept this answer in a minute.

Comment: There were a few floaters when the hull was breached. Not sure which episode/movie, but yeah. There were casualties that went space walkabout...

Comment: @MajorStackings : That's another film, *Nemesis*, after *First Contact*.  The bridge itself is torn open and a person is sucked out into space...I'll add that.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: If that scene in Nemesis counts, there's a similar shot of a Romulan in the TNG episode "The Next Phase"

Comment: @Praxis:  the question doesn't ask for controlled locomotion.  Just 0g.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Also, when I saw the question, I was certain you had asked it!  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis:  heh, well I wouldn't ask that question since I know the answer.   At any rate,  I don't see the distinction you're making on free-floating.   A physicist like you knows all motion is relative.   A dead Romulan is free-floating in 0g to me.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I was fixating more on actual space walking or casual floating...didn't realize the question was about anything to do with zero gravity.  Below the question, I recommended that the OP accept your answer instead, given that yours is in the episodes themselves!

Comment: "an officer is sucked out into space" - [actually, an officer is *blown* out into space.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vObSEL57n2I)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   I see the reference, but I have to differ with Data.   What's the difference?  Sucking/blowing is always when an object experiences a force from higher to lower pressure.   It's only a matter of perspective.   If you believe 'sucking' is incorrect, you're arguing the word shouldn't exist because it's always wrong.   Screw off pedantic Mr. Data.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: That has already been [discussed on Space Exploration SE](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5947/is-the-air-sucked-out-or-blown-out-into-space-when-the-hatch-opens).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   I call BS on that.   I like the idea, but the Enteprise doesn't necessarily have compressors.   It may not be actively running machinery to keep the atmospheric pressure in the ship at target.   All it needs to do that is have the right amount of air present -- the ship is sealed.   Presumably it adds or removes air as needed.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: While [one answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/5950) mentions compressors, it also mentions "the power source (...) that moves the air". The answer doesn't get quite clear there, so it doesn't quite express the interpretation that a spaceship could be seen as an intentionally pressurized thing brought into a low-pressure environment (space), and thereby involuntarily becomes a "power source" in the event of a hull breach. The [other answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/5949/11625), however, also points out that it is normally indeed the air being sucked out that ...

Comment: ... moves an unfortunate person in the vicinity of a hull breach, not the pressure difference itself (which would probably only happen if the person actually clogs the opening). By that interpretation, the air is indeed *sucked* out, and while that happens, persons can be *blown* out.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   I just thing it's useless pedantry ignoring that what really matters the real usage of language and whether you can communicate the intended meaning.   This is like arguing or the usage of 'literally' or 'I could care less'.    Either 'suck' or 'blow' is fine.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : Have you ever had bubble tea with tapioca pearls in it?  Through the straw, we suck into our mouths the tea.  Along with the upward-flowing tea comes the tapioca pearls.  One is more likely to say that we have sucked the pearls into our mouths, as opposed to saying that the pearls were blown into our mouths.  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis: Indeed, because tea does not blow. The bubbles float within the tea, so they float into our mouths :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : Just having a bit of fun.  A cup of bubble tea is not a pressurized container, of course. ;-) But tapioca pearls do not float in my experience.  They stay at the bottom of the cup until summoned by the straw...

Answer (score 7):

## Data in Star Trek: Nemesis

> After looking at each other and La Forge proudly nodding to him, La
>   Forge activates another force field between him and Data, and then as
>   Data runs toward the hole in the ship, La Forge deactivates that force
>   field which, as he leaps, **blows Data out of the Enterprise and Data
>   flies toward the Scimitar**. When he reaches it, he grabs hold and
>   activates a hatch, allowing him access.

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis)

Comment: That's a good one, too!  :-)

Comment: Can't find a video of the section at the moment sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Does Deanna Troi floating in [Night Terrors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Terrors_(episode)) count?

[image]

That's more of a dream sequence than reality but I think the intent is zero gravity. AFAIK, no one was really happy with these "convincing zero-g effects".

Comment: That is painful to watch

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Yeah, pretty terrible. But not terrible enough to wrap around negative infinity and become genius.

Comment: This seems to fit the description.

Comment: @muistooshort:   Well, "Night Terrors" is floating in a dream.   It's not incontrovertible that that's zero-g.   People float in dreams all the time.   People do it in non-scifi shows too, so I'm not convinced it counts.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Still better flying than [Pumaman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHMPR7kXJak)

Comment: Good episode, though.

Comment: @SpaceIsBig42: I don't know about that, Pumaman was terrible enough to be a great badfilm, I've enjoyed it every time I've watched it. Maybe I just like bad movies though.

Answer (score 0):

The DS9 Episode "Melora" revolved around an engineer from a low-gravity planet whose quarters had the gravity plating turned off. She and Dr. Bashir "danced" there.

Comment: The question is TNG specific.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to mention a scene in a season 1 Enterprise episode where the gravity gets turned off during one of their gratuitous shower scenes.  But not TNG, so doesn't count.